# Cannot insert data into SQL db using PDO SQLSRV

Tags: php, api, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm trying to learn to create a simple CRUD API for sql server database. For now, I only manage to select table from the database and now I'm moving on to insert data into the database.

But I have problem inserting values into my local SQL Server DB using PDO SQLSRV. Please guide me to fix my code.

For your information, my sql table only use *nvarchar*, *datetime*, *int* and *numeric* data types.

**Table structure**

```
AcCustomerID            | nvarchar(20)
AcCustomerName          | nvarchar(100)
AcTermID                | nvarchar(20)
AcAreaID                | nvarchar(20)
AcCusGroupID            | nvarchar(20)
AcCusUDGroupID          | nvarchar(20)
BillingAddress1         | nvarchar(100)
BillingAddress2         | nvarchar(100)
BillingAddress3         | nvarchar(100)
BillingAddress4         | nvarchar(100)
BillingTel1             | nvarchar(100)
BillingTel2             | nvarchar(100)
BillingFax1             | nvarchar(100)
BillingFax2             | nvarchar(100)
BillingPostalCode       | nvarchar(10)
BillingContact1         | nvarchar(100)
BillingContact2         | nvarchar(100)
BillingEmail            | nvarchar(100)
BillingHomePage         | nvarchar(100)
IsActive                | nvarchar(1)
Notes                   | nvarchar(MAX)
CreateBy                | nvarchar(20)
CreateDate              | datetime
EditBy                  | nvarchar(20)
EditDate                | datetime
Stamp                   | int
AcCustomerNickName      | nvarchar(100)
DateOfBirth             | datetime
IsMember                | nvarchar(1)
Gender                  | nvarchar(1)
MemberNo                | nvarchar(100)
MobileNo                | nvarchar(100)
IdentityNo              | nvarchar(100)
MemberJoinDate          | datetime
MemberExpireDate        | datetime
MemberMarriageDate      | datetime
AcMemberEthnicID        | nvarchar(20)
AcMemberIncomeID        | nvarchar(20)
AcMemberOccupationID    | nvarchar(20)
MemberPointBalance      | numeric(18, 2)
MemberPointAccumulated  | numeric(18, 4)
PriceCode               | nvarchar(1)
AcSalesmanID            | nvarchar(20)
IsGSTRegister           | nvarchar(1)
GSTRegisterNumber       | nvarchar(30)
BusinessRegisterNumber  | nvarchar(30)
AcCurrencyID            | nvarchar(5)
IsAllowPrintStatement   | nvarchar(1)
IsAllowExceedCreditTerm | nvarchar(1)
IsAllowExceedCreditLimit| nvarchar(1)
LocalCreditLimit        | numeric(18, 2)
LocalBalanceAmount      | numeric(18, 2)
AcTaxID                 | nvarchar(20)
IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS| nvarchar(1)
MemberNotes             | nvarchar(MAX)
AcINCardPackageID       | nvarchar(20)
AcCustomerIDParentID    | nvarchar(20)
TaxSLTRegistrationNo    | nvarchar(40)
TaxSVTRegistrationNo    | nvarchar(40)
AcTaxIDSST              | nvarchar(20)
SSTExemptionCertNumber  | nvarchar(30)
```

**config/database.php**

```
<?php
    class Database
    { 
        // specify your own database credentials
        private $host = "localhost\QNEBSS";
        private $db_name = "cafe99";
        private $username = "sa";
        private $password = "QnE123!@#";
        public $conn;

        // get the database connection
        public function getConnection()
        {

            $this->conn = null;

            try
            {
                $this->conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=".$this->host.";Database=".$this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
                $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
            }
            catch(PDOException $exception)
            {
                echo json_encode(array("message" => "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage()));
            }

            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
?>
```

**objects/customer.php**

```
<?php
    class Customer
    { 
        // database connection and table name
        private $conn;
        private $table_name = "AcCustomer";

        // object properties
        public $AcCustomerID, $AcCustomerName, $AcTermID, $AcAreaID, $AcCusGroupID, $AcCusUDGroupID,
        $BillingAddress1, $BillingAddress2, $BillingAddress3, $BillingAddress4, $BillingTel1,
        $BillingTel2, $BillingFax1, $BillingFax2, $BillingPostalCode, $BillingContact1,
        $BillingContact2, $BillingEmail, $BillingHomePage, $IsActive, $Notes,
        $CreateBy, $CreateDate, $EditBy, $EditDate, $Stamp, $AcCustomerNickName,
        $DateOfBirth, $IsMember, $Gender, $MemberNo, $MobileNo, $IdentityNo,
        $MemberJoinDate, $MemberExpireDate, $MemberMarriageDate, $AcMemberEthnicID,
        $AcMemberIncomeID, $AcMemberOccupationID, $MemberPointBalance, $MemberPointAccumulated,
        $PriceCode, $AcSalesmanID, $IsGSTRegister, $GSTRegisterNumber, $BusinessRegisterNumber,
        $AcCurrencyID, $IsAllowPrintStatement, $IsAllowExceedCreditTerm, $IsAllowExceedCreditLimit,
        $LocalCreditLimit, $LocalBalanceAmount, $AcTaxID, $IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS,
        $MemberNotes, $AcINCardPackageID, $AcCustomerIDParentID, $TaxSLTRegistrationNo,
        $TaxSVTRegistrationNo, $AcTaxIDSST, $SSTExemptionCertNumber;


        // constructor with $db as database connection
        public function __construct($db)
        {
            $this->conn = $db;
        }

        // read customers
        function read()    
        {    
            // select all query
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." ORDER BY AcCustomerName ASC";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

            // execute query
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }

        // create product
        function create()
        {
            // query to insert record
            $query = "INSERT INTO
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                    (
                        AcCustomerID, AcCustomerName, AcTermID,
                        AcAreaID, AcCusGroupID, AcCusUDGroupID,
                        BillingEmail, IsActive, CreateBy,
                        CreateDate, Stamp, DateOfBirth,
                        IsMember, Gender, MobileNo,
                        MemberJoinDate, MemberExpireDate, MemberMarriageDate,
                        AcMemberEthnicID, AcMemberIncomeID, AcMemberOccupationID,
                        MemberPointBalance, MemberPointAccumulated, PriceCode,
                        AcSalesmanID, IsGSTRegister, AcCurrencyID,
                        IsAllowPrintStatement, IsAllowExceedCreditTerm, IsAllowExceedCreditLimit,
                        LocalCreditLimit, LocalBalanceAmount, IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS,
                        AcCustomerIDParentID
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        :AcCustomerID, :AcCustomerName, :AcTermID,
                        :AcAreaID, :AcCusGroupID, :AcCusUDGroupID,
                        :BillingEmail, :IsActive, :CreateBy,
                        :CreateDate, :Stamp, :DateOfBirth,
                        :IsMember, :Gender, :MobileNo,
                        :MemberJoinDate, :MemberExpireDate, :MemberMarriageDate,
                        :AcMemberEthnicID, :AcMemberIncomeID, :AcMemberOccupationID,
                        :MemberPointBalance, :MemberPointAccumulated, :PriceCode,
                        :AcSalesmanID, :IsGSTRegister, :AcCurrencyID,
                        :IsAllowPrintStatement, :IsAllowExceedCreditTerm, :IsAllowExceedCreditLimit,
                        :LocalCreditLimit, :LocalBalanceAmount, :IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS,
                        :AcCustomerIDParentID
                    )";

            // prepare query
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            // bind values
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCustomerID", $this->AcCustomerID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCustomerName", $this->AcCustomerName);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcTermID", $this->AcTermID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcAreaID", $this->AcAreaID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCusGroupID", $this->AcCusGroupID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCusUDGroupID", $this->AcCusUDGroupID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":BillingEmail", $this->BillingEmail);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsActive",$this->IsActive);
            $stmt->bindParam(":CreateBy",$this->CreateBy);
            $stmt->bindParam(":CreateDate",$this->CreateDate);
            $stmt->bindParam(":Stamp",$this->Stamp);
            $stmt->bindParam(":DateOfBirth",$this->DateOfBirth);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsMember",$this->IsMember);
            $stmt->bindParam(":Gender",$this->Gender);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MobileNo",$this->MobileNo);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MemberJoinDate",$this->MemberJoinDate);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MemberExpireDate",$this->MemberExpireDate);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MemberMarriageDate",$this->MemberMarriageDate);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcMemberEthnicID",$this->AcMemberEthnicID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcMemberIncomeID",$this->AcMemberIncomeID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcMemberOccupationID",$this->AcMemberOccupationID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MemberPointBalance",$this->MemberPointBalance);
            $stmt->bindParam(":MemberPointAccumulated",$this->MemberPointAccumulated);
            $stmt->bindParam(":PriceCode",$this->PriceCode);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcSalesmanID",$this->AcSalesmanID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsGSTRegister",$this->IsGSTRegister);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCurrencyID",$this->AcCurrencyID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsAllowPrintStatement",$this->IsAllowPrintStatement);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsAllowExceedCreditTerm",$this->IsAllowExceedCreditTerm);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsAllowExceedCreditLimit",$this->IsAllowExceedCreditLimit);
            $stmt->bindParam(":LocalCreditLimit",$this->LocalCreditLimit);
            $stmt->bindParam(":LocalBalanceAmount",$this->LocalBalanceAmount);
            $stmt->bindParam(":IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS",$this->IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS);
            $stmt->bindParam(":AcCustomerIDParentID",$this->AcCustomerIDParentID);

            // execute query
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

**customer/create.php**

```
<?php
    // required headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    // get database connection
    include_once '../config/database.php';

    // instantiate product object
    include_once '../objects/customer.php';

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $customer = new Customer($db);

    // get posted data
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    // make sure data is not empty
    if(!empty($data->AcCustomerID) 
        && !empty($data->AcCustomerName) 
        && !empty($data->BillingEmail) 
        && !empty($data->DateOfBirth) 
        && !empty($data->MobileNo)
    )
    {    
        // set product property values
        $customer->AcCustomerID = $data->AcCustomerID;
        $customer->AcCustomerName = $data->AcCustomerName; 
        $customer->AcTermID = "CASH";
        $customer->AcAreaID = "NA";
        $customer->AcCusGroupID = "NA";
        $customer->AcCusUDGroupID = "NA";
        $customer->BillingEmail = $data->BillingEmail;
        $customer->IsActive = "Y";
        $customer->CreateBy = "APP";
        $customer->CreateDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
        $customer->Stamp = "0";
        $customer->DateOfBirth = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($data->DateOfBirth));
        $customer->IsMember = "Y";
        $customer->Gender = "NA";
        $customer->MobileNo = $data->MobileNo;
        $customer->MemberJoinDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
        $customer->MemberExpireDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime('+1 year'));
        $customer->MemberMarriageDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
        $customer->AcMemberEthnicID = "NA" ;
        $customer->AcMemberIncomeID = "NA";
        $customer->AcMemberOccupationID = "NA";
        $customer->MemberPointBalance = "0.00";
        $customer->MemberPointAccumulated = "0.0000";
        $customer->PriceCode = "1";
        $customer->AcSalesmanID = "NA";
        $customer->IsGSTRegister = "N";
        $customer->AcCurrencyID = "MYR";
        $customer->IsAllowPrintStatement = "N";
        $customer->IsAllowExceedCreditTerm = "N";
        $customer->IsAllowExceedCreditLimit = "N";
        $customer->LocalCreditLimit = "0.00";
        $customer->LocalBalanceAmount = "0.00";
        $customer->IsAllowCreditSalesForPOS = "N";
        $customer->AcCustomerIDParentID = $data->AcCustomerID;            

        // create the product
        /*if($customer->create())
        {

            // set response code - 201 created
            http_response_code(201);

            // tell the user
            //echo json_encode(array("message" => "New Member was created."));
        }

        // if unable to create the product, tell the user
        else
        {

            // set response code - 503 service unavailable
            http_response_code(503);

            // tell the user
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create new member."));
        }*/

        try 
        {
            if($customer->create())
            {

                // set response code - 201 created
                http_response_code(201);

                // tell the user
                echo json_encode(array("message" => "New Member was created."));
            }
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo json_encode(array("message" => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    // tell the user data is incomplete
    else
    {

        // set response code - 400 bad request
        http_response_code(400);

        // tell the user
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create new member. Data is incomplete."));
    }
?>
```

**Output**
[image: output]

Comment: I'm not to familiar with your framework but regardless of language and framework it seems like you're not handling exceptions correctly. There should be a way to wrap you code in a `try/catch` and catch the exception with the correct error message that will have additional information here's a quick example https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php `echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";` in the catch statement. Currently it seems like you're not handling that correctly which will have more information to help debug your issue.

Comment: That table has a lot of columns, have you tried inserting to a table that has less columns first? it would make troubleshooting a lot easier.

Comment: @RyDog I have put `try/catch` on my customer/create.php and I think it got to do with datetime data type?

Comment: @Richmond sql dattime format is supposed to look like this: '2019-12-04 00:00:00'. try remove the '.u' from all your date functions. eg date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'); becomes date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: @RyDog I have tested using table that have less columns. Yes, it should be `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. Now I still have problem which show this message `String or binary data would be truncated`, I have 2 column that used numeric data types. Is it `$customer->variable = "0.00"; or $customer->variable = ".00" ;` ?

Comment: @Richmond if the value is 0 you could just use $customer->variable = 0; try remove the double quotes around your numbers if its complaining about strings

Comment: @RyDog still not working. Is `bindparam` has to do with it?

Comment: can you include a copy of the table structure

Comment: @RyDog I have included my table structure on my post

Comment: Gender is set to nvarchar(1) but you are setting it to 'NA' in your code. so thats 2 characters, it wont be hapy about that.

Comment: @RyDog Damn, my bad. I never thought of checking the table structure. By the way, thanks for helping.

Comment: all good! Ill put it as an swer. so we can close this off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues

1. Your datetime format is incorrect, you have it as `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');`, when it should be `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
2. Gender is being set to 'NA' (2 characters) when the table has Gender as nvarchar(1) meaning only one character only. Change the Gender to one character or increase the nvarchar limit.